# Append Complex Data (duplicate images)

Tags: import, image, csv, product-images, image-upload

Way the Append Complex Data keeps adding (duplicate) the pictures every time I do the import. Can this been change? All other data (attributes) are not duplicated, just the images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment yet so i have to do it this way. I'm kindly asking you to add more information to your question. Based on your description and the tags you are trying to import some data through CSV and your images become duplicate? Do you use a dataflow profile? I don't have enough information to determine your exact problem.

I myself find magento's CSV import sometimes a pain in the em.. butt. Therefore i always use Magmi to import my CSV files. It's faster and has a lot of features which makes importing data easier. The following link goes to the Magmi Wiki of Image attributes processor. Maybe Magmi can be your solution. Goodluck.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Comment: Thank you for your effort and working with me. I'm using basic/default import csv (not dataflow). Import is working fine, and I have two choices to append and to replace. Append, for some reson would be better in my case, but it keeps adding duplicate images.

Comment: Append basically means add to so getting duplicate images will be the result of that. I'm not sure but i think replace would solve that becouse it overwrites data. It won't delete anything if it's not overwritten. You should test that first in a development environment before doing it live. I always use Magmi or the dataflow profile so i'm not sure.

Comment: I'm sorry. Is it so that you already have product data and you want to add more but in your import file the products that already have been imported are still there? Using append would be logic but than you need to remove the entries you already imported. Magmi has the options to: update existing items, skip new ones - create new items & update existing ones - create new items only, skip existing ones. One of these options will suit your needs.

Comment: I need to figure out the update before I go live with my site. I have been using replace existing complex data, which was working great by the way. Speed of the importation is very vast, it takes 15sec to update aprox. 300 products. But the problem with the replace existing complex data is that i need to check the categories again after every importation of the products.

Comment: I will give a try to magmi.

Comment: You're close to your solution. I have spend countless hours on product imports through CSV so i feel your pain. I can be found on skype with the same name if you have some quick question. I'm currently working on my own sites so i might not respond. But feel free to ask :)

Comment: you are the man. will let you know about the income :)